# php.ini - Can't find the correct file to edit

Tags: php, apache2

I'm trying to adjust **max_execution_time** and **memory_limit** directives.

**phpinfo()** output:

```
Server API  FPM/FastCGI Virtual Directory Support   disabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /etc/php/7.0/fpm Loaded
Configuration File  /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini 
Scan this dir for additional .ini files /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d
```

I have updated both directives in

> /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini

and restarted apache2 but no luck.

**php -r 'print php_ini_loaded_file(); print_r(php_ini_scanned_files());'** output:

```
/etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini/
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-apcu.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-imagick.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-imap.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-intl.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-memcache.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_sqlite.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-pspell.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-recode.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sqlite3.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-tidy.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-wddx.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xmlrpc.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-zip.ini
```

**php --ini** ouput:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php/7.0/cli
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini,
```

I have updated both directives in

> /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini/

and restared apache2 but again no luck.

**find / -type f -name "php.ini"** ouput:

```
/etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
/etc/php/7.0/cgi/php.ini
/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini
/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini
```

Again, I have updated both directives in all *.php.ini files and restarted apache2 but still **phpinfo()** displays old settings.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you restart php (php-fpm) ?

Comment: I forgot about it! Haha, thank you very much @Gerard H. Pille :) Please post this as answer and I will mark this as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Php-fpm runs independently from Apache, so it needs a reload or restart to see the new directives.  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [configuration layout](https://wiki.debian.org/PHP#Configuration_layout) this seems a Debian based system.

> For each `major.minor` release `M.N` of PHP (where M is 7 and N is 0,
>   1, ...), each of the SAPI's (apache2/cgi/fpm/cli/phpdbg/...) have a
>   different central configuration file `/etc/php/M.N/$SAPI/php.ini`

Based on the output of `phpinfo()` Apache is using the PHP FPM/FastCGI as the *Server Application Programming Interface* (SAPI). Therefore, the configuration files in `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/` are used. Reloading the configuration requires reloading the PHP-FPM (separate from Apache):

```
sudo systemctl reload php7.0-fpm
```

When you use PHP from the command line, [CLI SAPI](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.introduction.php) is used, instead, so `/etc/php/7.0/cli/` is in use. The PHP CLI reads the configuration when you launch the command. That's why the commands you used for testing gave conflicting results.